# Serving images from Azure Blob Storage in dot net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I am attempting to write some Middleware to serve Azure Blobs via proxy.  The handler is being called, the blob is being retrieved, but my image is not being displayed.

I wrote a service to connect to the Storage Account and create a Blob Client.  I wrote middleware that consumes the service and then downloads the requested blob and writes it to the Response.  Normally, I would expect to download the blob as a byte array or a stream and write it to the OutputStream and that does not seem to be an option using the new httpContext in .net core.

My Middleware:

```
namespace SampleApp1.WebApp.Middleware
{
    public class BlobFileViewHandler
    {
        public BlobFileViewHandler(RequestDelegate next)
        {
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IBlobService svc)
        {
            string container = httpContext.Request.Query["container"];
            string itemPath = httpContext.Request.Query["path"];

            Blob cbb = await svc.GetBlobAsync(container, itemPath);

            httpContext.Response.ContentType = cbb.ContentType;
            await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(cbb.Contents, 0, cbb.Contents.Length);            
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class BlobFileViewHandlerExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseBlobFileViewHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<BlobFileViewHandler>();
        }
    }
}
```

I call the middleware using the Map function in Startup as below:

```
app.Map(new PathString("/thumbs"), a => a.UseBlobFileHandler());
```

And finally, I attempt to use that handler on a test page as follows:

`<img src="~/thumbs?qs=1" alt="thumbtest" />`

When I debug I can see all the correct parts being hit, but the image never loads, I just get the following:

[image: broken image]

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I'm not sure what that is. I am using NetCoreApp Version 1.1.

Comment: I tried your solution, beceuse it is what I need, but have a problem with the following line
app.Map(new PathString("/thumbs"), a => a.UseBlobFileHandler());

can u do more explanation pls. thnx

Comment: app.Map() just short-circuits the pipeline and lets the runtime know that any request to the given path is to be handled by the middleware indicated.  This is how HttpHandlers are modeled in .net core.

Comment: I understand that, but it shows me an error for a => a.UseBlobFileHandler()

Comment: I updated my question to give you the whole picture of my current handler. Maybe that will answer your question about the extension method usage.

Comment: Thank you, I managed it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess I jumped the gun a little early, because it appears you CAN write to the OutputStream, it's just referenced a little differently. Below is the working implementation of what I was attempting in the middleware:

```
public class BlobFileHandler
{
    public BlobFileHandler(RequestDelegate next)
    {
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string container = "<static container reference>";
        string itemPath = "<static blob reference>";
        //string response;
        IBlobService svc = (IBlobService)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IBlobService));

        CloudBlockBlob cbb = svc.GetBlob(container, itemPath);

        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";//cbb.Properties.ContentType;            
        await cbb.DownloadToStreamAsync(httpContext.Response.Body);
    }
}
```